# Bjarne Stroustrup Book - std_lib_facilities.h - won't work (unknown type name)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am studying from Bjarne Stroustrup's book "Programming - Principles and Practice using C++". In his book he asked to include "std_lib_facilities.h". So I got part of code like this

```
#ifndef H112
#define H112 020215L


#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream> 
#include<sstream> 
#include<cmath> 
#include<cstdlib> 
#include<string> 
#include<list>
#include <forward_list>
#include<vector> 
#include<unordered_map>
#include<algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <regex>
#include<random>
#include<stdexcept>

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#if __GNUC__ && __GNUC__ < 5
inline ios_base & defaultfloat(ios_base& b)    // to augment fixed and scientific as in C++11
{
    b.setf(ios_base::fmtflags(0), ios_base::floatfield);
    return b;
}
#endif
```

Xcode won't compile my project and show me error

> - unknown type name in this part
> - Unknown type name 'ios_base'; did you mean 'std::ios_base'? Replace 'ios_base' with 'std::ios_base'

at

```
inline ios_base & defaultfloat(ios_base& b)
```

and also show me error

> Use of undeclared identifier 'ios_base'; did you mean 'std::ios_base'?

at

```
b.setf(ios_base::fmtflags(0), ios_base::floatfield);
```

so I changed all ios_base to std::ios_base
but it won't compile my project still....

Comment: It seems like a bug in `std_lib_facilities.h`, though I'm unsure why. Bjarne uses `ios_base` unqualified, which seems strange. That section is only enabled on versions of GCC older than 5, which I guess you're using. What is the error you get after you qualify the names?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help man :) It was same that the error I got after qualified the names. but after I restarted it worked perfectly. I think it might be problem of my computer

Comment: OK. It did not make sense that it would still complain once the names were qualified, so I'm glad for that. I turned this into an answer as well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like a bug in the file. That section is a "recent" addition, which should only run under GCC versions prior to version 5, but `ios_base` is used unqualified *before* the using-directive.

The "correct" fix is to qualify all uses of `ios_base` with `std::`:

```
inline std::ios_base & defaultfloat(std::ios_base& b)
{
    b.setf(std::ios_base::fmtflags(0), std::ios_base::floatfield);
    return b;
}
```

Alternatively, you can move the `using namespace std;` statement up before the code snippet in the file. That is not a pretty solution, but Bjarne's point with this header was not to demonstrate good coding practices, but to hide some complexity from beginners.

In any case, as soon as you've progressed far enough, you should stop using the header completely and do things *right*. The book tells you when.

Answer (score 1):

T @ravnsgaard 
As a self-directed student was looking for a solution to this header issue for some time. This solution worked so long as I referenced C++11 during compilation:
e.g. g++ -std=c++11 yourfile.cpp -o yourfile